# How do I combine arrays and map and do something with it?

Tags: java

I have two arrays

```
String[] names = {“bob”, “rob”};    //There are multiple arrays for various scenarios names1, names2 and so on…
String[] features = {“age”, “weight”}; //There are multiple array for various scenarios features1 features2 and so on…
```

and a HashMap in a class which has keys and values  for
age, weight, gender, occupation……

I get values from it like this:

```
public ClassToGetValues (String name) {    

public String getValue(String key) {
                return map.get(key);
            }

    private void buildMap(Paramenter1 paramenter1, Paramenter2, paramenter2) {
                map.put("name", someFunction());
            map.put(....
        }
    }
```

I use these arrays and map to print  following:
bob 30yr 160lbs
rob 40yr 170lbs

```
  private static void printMethod(String[] names, String[] features) {

        for (String name : names) {
            ClassToGetValues classToGetValues = new ClassToGetValues(name);
            for (String feature : features) {
                System.out.print(classToGetValues.getValue(feature) + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Now I want to create few methods like

method 1

```
 public String criteriaOne(int age, int weight) {
        if (age > 35 && weight > 160) {
            // "Do something";
        }
         return names;
    }
```

method 2

```
 public String criteriaTwo(int age, String gender) {
            if (age <70 && gender == “male”) {
                // "Do something";
            }
             return names;
        }
```

How do I  start in creating these methods?

Comment: Java is an object oriented programming language, you should use objects for your data and this problem will be a lot simpler.

Comment: You should think more functionally and look into lambdas.  All those criteria fit perfectly into the interfaces in the java.util.function package.

Comment: Solve the solution in a manner belonging to the language. Thus create a class containing the structure you need, not by using arrays and maps.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you would create a class Person to store data related to a person rather than holding those data losely in different data structures. Well, there may be some external constraints that make you do it even though java is not meant to be used like that. My advice is, create a class and hold a list or map of that type:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double weight;

    public Person(String name, int age, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = String.format("Person %s is %d years old and weighs %f lbs", name, String.valueOf(age), String.valueOf(double));
        return s;
    }
```

then you create a single `List<Person>`, add some `Person`s and print out every `Person`'s data like

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons.add(new Person("Bob", 23, 160);
persons.add(new Person("Rob", 20, 120);
for (Person p : persons) {
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```